Painting over peeling paint?
So during covid lockdown, I had the bright idea of painting this room dark gray using some of the more expensive Sherwin Williams paint, and no longer want to have a dark colored bedroom.
Unfortunately, the paint has always peeled like this. At first, I never thought much of it and only really noticed the peeling because of a few accidental scratches while moving furniture. I think the paint container had said it could take 20+ days to fully cure, so I can't say I was terribly concerned then. Unfortunately that was something around 4 years ago now, and it still peels like this
What I've done so far is:

Use a scraper to scrape off what comes off easily
Sand the walls
Purchased bonding primer

Things felt like they were going well, but after sanding yesterday, more of this stuff is peeling in larger pieces, which i think may partially have been a symptom of the humidity level (video is of my sister enjoying peeling the paint). Ideally, I would LOVE to not have to go back and peel the entirety of the room, and I'm hoping I can just chalk it up the humidity yesterday.
Today, I intend to put in a window AC unit to alleviate the heat/humidity problem. I would love advice on if its possible to put primer over this kind of peeling? Would two coats of it help?
Or just anything to help me avoid having to peel the entire room because that would make this project take a lot longer than I would like
Thank you all in advance for your help!

Humidity wasn't a factor. I have decades of painting experience in my often juicy climate and it's never been an issue other than with respect to dry times. The type and condition of the underlying finish was a factor. What was it? No, painting over flakes is not wise, and more coats is just more wasted money. What's on top doesn't change what's underneath.

Putting paint over peeling paint is a waste of money/paint/labour. Remove all peeling, clean all dirt/dust/oil off the walls then repeat. after you may paint.  Good prep job should suck doing, but you save money on not painting every few months.

Depending on the amount of peeling, it may make more sense to simply replace the drywall (if you own, not rent).  Yes, there will be more debris to deal with and you may need to do some drywall finishing, but you'll have a guaranteed good substrate for the new paint.
